# Fetch the records from current month

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to pull the `TOTAL_PRICE` from the cart table using the the following query. Currently it will fetch the `TOTAL_PRICE` from last 30 days. But I need to modify the query to fetch the `TOTAL_PRICE` of the current month.
ie, `PURCHASED_DATE` should be in between 1 to 30/31 of the current month.

```
SELECT TOTAL_PRICE
FROM CUST_CART_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID      = '"+userId+"'
AND (PURCHASED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE-30, 'DD-MM-YY') AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YY')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TRUNC and LAST_DAY:

```
SELECT TOTAL_PRICE
FROM CUST_CART_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID      = '"+userId+"'
AND (TRUNC(PURCHASED_DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') AND TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)));
```

Comment: This will miss the records that belong to the last day of the month.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man It won't if the `PURCHASE_DATE` is truncated - I assumed it was. Anyway, thanks, I've added the `TRUNC` to `PURCHASE_DATE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one -

```
SELECT TOTAL_PRICE
    FROM CUST_CART_TABLE
    WHERE USER_ID      = '"+userId+"'
AND TRUNC(PURCHASED_DATE,'MONTH') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH');
```

It will return records from the current month.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT TOTAL_PRICE
FROM CUST_CART_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID='"+userId+"' AND 
TRUNC(PURCHASED_DATE) BETWEEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))+1 AND 
                        LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT TOTAL_PRICE
    FROM CUST_CART_TABLE
    WHERE USER_ID      = '"+userId+"'
    AND (PURCHASED_DATE BETWEEN 
SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND
 SELECT DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply compare the month, i.e. 'mm' in combination with 'yyyy':

```
SELECT TOTAL_PRICE
FROM CUST_CART_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID = '"+userId+"'
AND TO_CHAR(PURCHASED_DATE,'yyyymm') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyymm');
```